# EF Core query not reflecting updated property without saving

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

With this code snippet, I query for an entity in my SQL database, and then update a property on that entity.

This query should filter out that entity because I just modified it, but the first one does not. For some reason, the second query does return what I expect.

In my scenario, the `ProductionOrderStep` entity is a one-to-many relationship to the `ProductionOrder` entity.

I do not want to add a call to `SaveChanges`.

Is this a bug in EF Core? Or is this intended behaviour?

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public void Test()
{
    var productionOrderStepId = 356664;
    var productionOrderId = 305712;

    var pos = context.ProductionOrderStep
                     .Where(x => x.ProductionOrderStepId == productionOrderStepId)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
    pos.Status = 2; // Changes status from 1 to 2

    var incorrectResult = context.ProductionOrder
                                 .Where(x => x.ProductionOrderId == productionOrderId)
                                 .SelectMany(x => x.ProductionOrderSteps)
                                 .Where(pos => pos.Status < 2)
                                 .ToList();

    var correctResult = context.ProductionOrder
                               .Where(x => x.ProductionOrderId == productionOrderId)
                               .SelectMany(x => x.ProductionOrderSteps)
                               .ToList()
                               .Where(pos => pos.Status < 2)
                               .ToList();
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options): base(options)
    {}

    public virtual DbSet<ProductionOrder> ProductionOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductionOrderStep> ProductionOrderStep { get; set; }
}

public class ProductionOrderStep
{
    public int ProductionOrderStepId { get; set; }
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductionOrder ProductionOrder { get; set; }
}

public class ProductionOrderStepConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductionOrderStep>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductionOrderStep> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(d => d.ProductionOrder)
               .WithMany(p => p.ProductionOrderSteps)
               .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductionOrderId);
    }
}

public class ProductionOrder
{
    public int ProductionOrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductionOrderStep> ProductionOrderSteps { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Queries are executed in the database. The DB does not yet know that `pos.Status` has changed.

Comment: SQL Server Database is multi-threaded and does not store/retrieve data in any particular order.  If you want data in order you must use ORDER BY.  First  will randomly return results.

Comment: You never save anything to the database. All changes are cached and persisted to the database *only* when `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` are called. If you execute new queries you're reloading the data from the database and generating new objects with those values

Comment: I flagged this `non-reproducible or caused by a typo` because there's no problem to reproduce. Nothing was saved in the database, so the query that *filters* by `Status` wouldn't return different result. The reason the second query seems to be "working" (it's not), is that EF caches objects. If it finds that an object is already cached based on its ID, it will return it. The second query loads all objects, without filtering, so the cached object with ID `correctResult` is returned. The second query then does something ugly by applying `Enumerable.Where` to the List in the same expression

Comment: after your status = 2, use a context.SaveChanges();
That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is intended behaviour. A basic breakdown of the behaviour you are seeing:

```
var incorrectResult = context.ProductionOrder  
    .Where(x => x.ProductionOrderId == productionOrderId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ProductionOrderSteps)
    .Where(pos => pos.Status < 2)
    .ToList();
```

This builds an SQL query that will attempt to load any ProductionOrderSteps for a given ProductionOrder where their Status < 2. That WHERE execution step goes to SQL. Since you have updated an entity and not committed the change to the database, that query will *not* know about your change so EF will not return your expected row.

```
var correctResult = context.ProductionOrder
    .Where(x => x.ProductionOrderId == productionOrderId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ProductionOrderSteps)
    .ToList()
    .Where(pos => pos.Status < 2)
    .ToList();
```

In this case, you are telling EF to run a query to load *all* Production Order Steps for a given Production Order. Since your updated entity is already tracked, EF will return that updated reference along with the other Production Order Steps that it might load from the DB. THe `Where` condition is done in-memory so the Status will reflect your updated change.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
This is part of a broader effort to limit the number of calls to SaveChanges in one API call in my application.
Based on your answer and the comments it seems like I'll need to test to see if this scenario works with explicit EF core transactions.